# Show that $\operatorname{int}{(A \times B)} = \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, product-space

The question goes as follows:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{U})$ be topological spaces. Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Show that $\operatorname{int} (A \times B) = \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$.

Here's my proof of the above:

The interior of a set $G$ is defined as
$$
x \in \operatorname{int}(G) \iff \exists \text{ an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\subseteq G$}
$$
Let $(x,y) \in \operatorname{int}(A \times B)$. This means there exists an open set $A_1 \times B_1$ containing $(x,y)$ such that $A_1 \times B_1 \subseteq A \times B \Rightarrow A_1 \subseteq A$ containing $x$ and  $B_1 \subseteq B$ containing $y$. Thus $(x, y) \in \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$.

Conversely, if $(x, y) \in \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$, then there exists open sets $A_1$ and $B_1$ containing $x$ and $y$ such that $A_1 \subseteq A$ and $B_1 \subseteq B$. So, $A_1 \times B_1$ is a open set in $A \times B$ containing $(x, y)$. Thus, $(x, y) \in \operatorname{int}(A \times B)$.

I am not quite sure about the correctness of my proof. So I thought I would check it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's correct as long as you know/state that you can find $A_{1}\times B_{1}$ such that $(x,y)\in A_{1}\times B_{1}\subseteq A\times B$ because product of open sets form a basis for the product topology.

Comment: Second part can be made simpler. Since $int(A)\times int(B)$ is open set in $A\times B$, we have $int(A)\times int(B)\subset int(A\times B)$.

Comment: @BobDobbs Thanks for the input